# Completing a hot observable chain with multiple hot observables

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

So I need to a complete a hot observable chain when the very first observable fires its completion handler.

An example is probably easier:

```
const hot1 = new Rx.Subject();
const hot2 = new Rx.Subject();

const example = hot1
  .do(() => console.log('HOT1 emitted'))
  .switchMap(() => hot2.do(() => console.log('HOT2 emitted')));

const subscribe = example.subscribe({
  next: console.log,
  error: console.error,
  complete: () => console.info('CHAIN COMPLETE')
});

hot1.next();
hot2.next('abc');

hot1.complete();
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/berexexoyu/edit?js,console

> I need `CHAIN COMPLETE` to be output when I call `hot1.complete()`.

Can this be solved functionally, without moving into imperative territory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might look like a little hack but since you want to control the chain only by completing `hot1` you can use `takeUntil` to complete chain after `hot1` completed while ignoring all its values:

```
const hot1 = new Subject();
const hot2 = new Subject();

const example = hot1
  .do(() => console.log('HOT1 emitted'))
  .switchMap(() => hot2.do(() => console.log('HOT2 emitted')))
  .takeUntil(hot1.ignoreElements().concat(Observable.of(1)));

const subscribe = example.subscribe({
  next: console.log,
  error: console.error,
  complete: () => console.info('CHAIN COMPLETE')
});

hot1.next();
hot2.next('abc');

hot1.complete();
```

See your updated demo (open console): https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs5-rfhpi2?file=index.ts

The trick is with using `hot1.ignoreElements().concat(Observable.of(1))` that emits a single value after `hot1` completes which notifies `takeUntil` and the whole chain is completed.

Comment: You could use the `last()` operator instead of `ignoreElements().concat(Observable.of(1))`.

Comment: Well, kind of. If `hot1` doesn't emit any value then `last()` will never emit anything and `example` won't complete either. Using `.concat(Observable.of(1)` guarantees it'll always emit.

Comment: Alright, a bit hacky as you said, but I can make it work. A quick question however: Lets say we have a bigger chain with more levels; will placing that in the end terminate the entire chain immediately upon `hot1.complete()`? (would be nice)

Comment: Yes, because the observer receives `complete` and the "Rx contract" dictates that it can always receive only one complete notification. So this makes the chain recursively dispose.